# Load documentation for Java Script functions in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

When we write code in C# and want to invoke a method we get full list of avaiable methods and their overloads with description of parameters and what the method does. As long as I remember this is not true for java script code.

How can I set up Visual Studio to get contextual help when calling a function in java script o jquery?

I selected all the features of Visual Studio Enterprise during installation

Comment: @MarcusH  Please check edit. Thank you. My question concerns many installations of VS on many computers.

Comment: If this is a common issue on multiple computers, mayby they can't reach the help files which is showed. If you run VS as admin, does it work? You can get the path in Tools->Options->Text Editor->JavaScript->IntelliSense->Reference

Comment: @MarcusH It can reach it, can I download more help files from some source?(I mean is there any better source than those default)?

Comment: Ok, really strange..Tools->Options->Text Editor->JavaScript->General-->Statement completion. Is Auto list members and parameter information checked? It's possible to add custom files but I don't know where to find other then the default.